# Copying Lists to Clipboard in Python 2.7.9 (Converting Complex Lists to Strings)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I'm trying to write a program that logs into a router, copies the output of a `show log` command to the clipboard, and pastes it to a text file or web page. I can get it to print the output I'm looking for. Here is a sample:

```
.Feb 27 07:25:28.050: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: Bad Checksum from 10.1.252.231, GigabitEthernet0/0/4

.Feb 27 07:25:38.135: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: Bad Checksum from 10.1.252.231, GigabitEthernet0/0/4

.Feb 27 07:25:53.001: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: Bad Checksum from 10.1.252.231, GigabitEthernet0/0/4

.Feb 27 07:26:02.746: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: Bad Checksum from 10.1.252.231, GigabitEthernet0/0/4

.Feb 27 07:26:12.033: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: Bad Checksum from 10.1.252.231, GigabitEthernet0/0/4

.Feb 27 07:26:21.517: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: Bad Checksum from 10.1.252.233, GigabitEthernet0/0/4

.Feb 27 07:26:35.721: %OSPF-4-ERRRCV: Received invalid packet: Bad Checksum from 10.1.252.233, GigabitEthernet0/0/4
```

However, my code segment for copying it to the clipboard returns the following error message:

```
TypeError: GTK.Clipboard.set_text() argument 1 must be string, not list
```

Any suggestions on how I could convert that output to a string data type?

Comment: `"\n".join(your_list)`?

Comment: Still getting the same error. Here is the code snippet: stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('show log')
Log = stdout.readlines()

"\n".join(Log)
pyperclip.copy(Log)

Comment: `"\n".join(Log)` returns string. So either do `Log = "\n".join(Log)` and then `pyperclip.copy(Log)`, or simply `pyperclip.copy("\n".join(Log))`

Comment: pyperclip.copy("\n".join(Log)) did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you have a list of strings which must be converter to the single string. Suppose that variable is called `strings`, then you need to do something like that:

```
... set_text("\n".join(strings))
```

Comment: Okay, I've added the statement set_text("\n".join(Log))    The error message says that 'set_text' is not defined. Is that a keyword for a particular library?

Comment: Well, you have to replace the argument in the ```set_text``` method from something like  ```.set_text(arg)``` to ```set_text("\n".join(arg))``` to be exact. Or if you don't call ```set_text``` method directly, you should apply that change to something which in turn calls that method.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following line of code resolved the issue and successfully copies the "show log" output to the clipboard: pyperclip.copy("\n".join(Log))

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on how I could convert that output to a string data type?

Using [join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) you can convert list to string.